# laravel remember function explanation

Tags: laravel

what's the difference beetween if I set second parameter of `Auth::attempt()` to true and false? If I close the browser and come to page I'm always logged in either if I set true or false. So I can't see any difference. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs at http://laravel.com/docs/security

> If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your application, you may pass true as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely (or until they manually logout). Of course, your users table must include the string remember_token column, which will be used to store the "remember me" token.

Laravel by default sets a session cookie upon authentication, with a lifetime configured in `app/config/session.php`. The default is 120 (minutes) which means your session will stay active for two hours after your last activity. With the remember me set to `true`, it will set an additional cookie to keep you logged in permanently.

Comment: Edited to explain a little more. Does that answer your question?